# jQuery.simplemodal-1.3.5 plugin: class selector disappears mysteriously

Tags: jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I have encountered the following issue:

A class definition added (programmatically) to an element inside the modal popup while the modal is active, is not retained after the model is closed. This is in contrast to a situation where the class definition is retained on the element after “hiding” and “showing” it via standard jQuery methods.

To illustrate the problem, please find below a test page.

Any explanation?

Thanks in advance,

-Itai

Click “jQuery Show Modal”

Click “Add Class”

Click “jQuery Hide Modal”

Click “jQuery Show Modal”

Click “Show Class” (You will see “aClass anotherClass”)

Click “jQuery Hide Modal”

Click SimpleModal Open

Click “Show Class” (You will see “aClass anotherClass”)

Click SimpleModal Close

Click “jQuery Show Modal”

Click “Remove Class”

Click “Show Class” (You will see only “aClass”)

Click “jQuery Hide Modal”

Click SimpleModal Open

Click “Add Class”

Click “Show Class” (You will see “aClass anotherClass”)

Click SimpleModal Close

Click SimpleModal Open

Click “Show Class” (You will see “aClass”) <-- Problem (anotherClass was not retained)

// Test.html
replace $link$ with

Test

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#btnjQueryShow").click(function(){
        $('#test-frame').show();
    });

    $("#btnQueryHide").click(function(){
        $('#test-frame').hide();
    });

    $("#btnAddClass").click(function(){
        $('#divClassHolder').addClass("anotherClass");
    });

    $("#btnRemoveClass").click(function(){
        $('#divClassHolder').removeClass("anotherClass");
    });

    $("#btnShowClass").click(function(){    
        var classNames = "";
        var classList = $('#divClassHolder').attr('class').split(' '); 
            $.each( classList, function(index, item){ 
                classNames += item + " ";
            }); 

        alert(classNames);
    });
});

</script>
```

```
<!-- DOM Show / Hide-->
<div>
    <input id="btnjQueryShow" type="button" value="jQuery Show Modal" />
    <input id="btnQueryHide" type="button" value="jQuery Hide Modal" />
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

$link$"#" id="popup-opener">SimpleModal Open</a>
<br>
<br>
<div id="test-frame" style="display:none; width:500px; background-color:white; border: solid 1px red">
    $link$"#" id="popup-closer" class="simplemodal-close" style="float:right;">SimpleModal Close</a><br>
    <div id="divClassHolder" class="aClass">
        <input id="btnAddClass"    type="button"  value="Add Class" />
        <input id="btnRemoveClass" type="button"  value="Remove Class" />
        <input id="btnShowClass"   type="button"  value="Show Class" />
    </div>
</div>
```

// popup.js

jQuery(function($) {
    var frm = {
        message: null,
        init: function() {
            $('#popup-opener').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

```
            $('#test-frame').modal(
 {
     overlayId: 'form-overlay',
     overlayCss: { backgroundColor: "#4178F0" },
     containerId: 'form-container',
     onOpen: frm.open,
     onShow: frm.show,
     close: false,
     minHeight: 590,
     minWidth: 635,
     position: ["5%", ],
  onClose: function(dialog) {
   $.modal.close();
  }
 });
        });
    },
    open: function(dialog) {

        // open handler
        dialog.overlay.show();

        dialog.container.show();

        dialog.data.show();            
        // file styles are not available in hidden divs!!
    },
    show: function(dialog) {

    },
    close: function(dialog) {

    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        // error handler
    },
    validate: function() {
        // validate handler
    },
    showError: function() {
        // error handler
    }
};

frm.init();
```

});

Answer (score 2):

By default, SimpleModal clones the content being used in the dialog. You have a few different options you can try.

1) Use the `persist` option:

```
$('#foo').modal({persist:true});
```

2) Add the class in the onShow callback:

```
$('#foo').modal({
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var classList = $('#divClassHolder', dialog.data[0]) ...
    }
});
```

Also, just wanted to mention that in the code you provided, using the onClose callback and calling `$.modal.close();` is not necessary. When the dialog closes, it will automatically perform that step.

Hope that helps.

-Eric